# String contains an untranslatable character

Tags: string

I am getting untranslatable characters from source so when i tried to load the data into target table i am getting this error. I am uisng teradata 16th version.

Sample record: NATL_SMB
Need output in this way: NATL_SMB

For these kind of data if it comes in any position then i want to remove only those data from that record.

i loaded this record from file to source table there itwas loaded with out any issues but when i troed to load the same thing from source to target then it is throwing an error saying it has (6706, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The string contains an untranslatable character.

Source and target both tables we created in teradata.

Source data type: VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
target data type VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC

Can anyone please help how to resolve this.

Respectfully
Prasad Mamidi